# Adding a custom class breaks Compose compilation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm just trying to get started with Android development and Kotlin using Jetpack Compose. Note that, I'm a Kotlin novice, so I'm trying to learn along the way. I come from JavaScript/TypeScript background, so I'm trying to learn by thinking in JavaScript terms and implement in Kotlin terms by searching online.

I'm trying to list all installed applications on the device. While the app was working as expected up till now, I needed to add a feature to sort the installed app names. I referred to: https://www.bezkoder.com/kotlin-sort-list-objects/#Create_Class_for_handling_sorting. As soon as I added a custom class to sort the `List<ApplicationInfo>`, my app stopped building.

I have included my repo here: https://github.com/Hrishikesh-K/TryKotlin

If I comment [these lines](https://github.com/Hrishikesh-K/TryKotlin/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/hrishikeshk/myapplication/MainActivity.kt#L19-L25) and [this line as well](https://github.com/Hrishikesh-K/TryKotlin/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/hrishikeshk/myapplication/MainActivity.kt#L37), the app builds fine. With the current setup, I get an error:

```
Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation
```

which points to line 21, character 18, which is the start of the word `compare`.

I don't understand why Compose would care about a custom class, it's not a Composable function after all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `compare` method you are using `LocalContext.current`

```
override fun compare(o1 : ApplicationInfo, o2 : ApplicationInfo): Int {
    return o1.loadLabel(LocalContext.current.packageManager).toString().compareTo(o2.loadLabel(LocalContext.current.packageManager).toString())
}
```

You can't use a `@Composable` functions if the method is not marked with the `@Composable`.

Use something different like:

```
data class CompareApplicationNames(val context: Context) : Comparator<ApplicationInfo> {

    override fun compare(o1 : ApplicationInfo, o2 : ApplicationInfo): Int {
        return o1.loadLabel(context.packageManager).toString().compareTo(o2.loadLabel(context.packageManager).toString())
    }
}
```

Then just use:

```
Log.d("sorted:", listOfApplications.sortedWith(CompareApplicationNames(LocalContext.current)).toString())
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you! Could you please tell me why LocalContext was causing issues? Why is it being treated as a Composable function? A link to some documentation would do.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate the function `current` is a `Composable`. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal.kt#L75)

Comment: Ahh, that clears it. Thank you!